# Scroll is not working when activity is in fullscreen mode in android?

Tags: android

Here i have a form with more than one EditText, so i put all this edittext in ScrollView.
And i set one ImageView which is fit with parent RelativeLayout.
I want activity in full screen mode and transparent status bar with white font(Light Theme) and whenever keyboard will appear Imageview not to resize(must be in fixed full screen size) and scroll enable on Edittext Focus. I tried many stackoverflow answer but didnt get right answer and this was is [one](https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/problem-solved-3-android-full-screen-view-translucent-scrollview-adjustresize-keyboard-b0547c7ced32) of them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SettingActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    


 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/setting_scrollview"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</ScrollView>

    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp">


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/male_avtar"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:onClick="settingProClick"/>
            <Button
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/third_button_bg_ppa"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/AppButtonTextColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                android:onClick="settingProClick"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/setting_profile_image"
                android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="this is a cool social media app androvilla"
                android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor"
                android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText">
                    <EditText
                        style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="first name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />
                    

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText">
                    <EditText
                        style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="last name"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText">
                    <EditText
                        style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="username"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <EditText
                            style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="country"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                            android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"

                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <EditText
                            
                            style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="username"
                            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                            android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                            android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText">
                    <EditText
                       
                        style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="birthdate"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                   
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/radio_group_title"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RadioGroup
                           
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <RadioButton
                               
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/AppFourthColor"
                                android:text="@string/radio_button_male"
                                android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/Text15" />

                            <RadioButton
                              
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/AppFourthColor"
                                android:text="@string/radio_button_female"
                                android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/Text15" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/AccountSettingEditText">
                    <EditText
                        style="@style/EditTextWoEnter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="relationship"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/Text17"
                        android:background="@color/AppTrasColor"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/AppDullTextColor"
                        android:textColor="@color/AppSecondColor" />
                   

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

in java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

             settingScrollView=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.setting_scrollview);
            settingScrollView.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

[image: this is my layout structure]

Comment: Here you use two scrollView. You should use only one scrollview. I think it will fine if you use only one scrollview.

Comment: first scroll is because of fixed position of Imagview when keyboard open